# The given data was invalid. when doing PHPunit testing

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm still new to laravel testing. I want to do testing on my store function. But I keep getting the error Call to The given data was invalid. [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Ce1.png).
my store function is :

```
       public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'companyLogo' => 'required',
        'companyName' => 'required',
        'companyDescription' => 'required',
    ]);

    $path = $request->file('companyLogo')->store('logo', 's3');
    Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path, 'public');

    $company = Company::create([
        'file_name' => basename($path),
        'company_field' => $request->companyField,
        'logo_url' => Storage::disk('s3')->url($path),
        'company_name' => $request->companyName,
        'employer_id' => $request->employerId,
        'company_address' => $request->companyAddress,
        'company_url' => $request->companyUrl,
        'email' => $request->companyEmail,
        'phone_number' => $request->companyPhone,
        'description' => $request->companyDescription,
    ]);

    $id = $request->employerId;
    return redirect('/companies' . '/' . $id)->with('status', 'Company Added Successfully!');
}
```

and my test function is

```
    public function test_user_register_company()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $user = $this->candidateRole();
    $this->actingAs($user);

    $response = $this->post('/companies', [
        'file_name' => '6eKnVlvM3zEhb8ly4OHedjMPeMplzgrTPi9K9JGt.png',
        'company_field' => 'Agriculture',
        'logo_url' => 'LOZ4QYc7Y2mR5gbs6wfJ',
        'company_name' => 'Company One',
        'employer_id' => $user->id,
        'company_address' => 'Jalan BEmliu9pcjKk4dKkb7Vd',
        'company_url' => 'imRGdojN0i',
        'email' => 'www.jN9nJHYZBv0NitDYKOYq.com',
        'phone_number' => '886797',
        'description' => 'iEwyNdrfAyFsOTeqv4OCnI3g2jYDEF3CPjqyqYAZ',
    ]);

    $this->assertCount(1, Company::all());
}
```

I still confused as to why I got that error.

the route is `Route::post('/companies', [CompaniesController::class, 'store']);`

Answer (score 0):

first off, your `companyLogo`, `companyName` and `companyDescription` are meant to be required from the validation in your controller store method and its not present is the data you are sending to the api on your test case

Comment: I changed `companyLogo`, `companyName`, and `companyDescription` to `logo_url`, `company_name`, and `descriprion`. It gave me `Error: Call to a member function store() on null`

Comment: This means you already updated $request->validate([
        'companyLogo' => 'required',
        'companyName' => 'required',
        'companyDescription' => 'required',
    ]);

Comment: also dont forget to check this $path = $request->file('companyLogo')->store('logo', 's3'); as this is where the store method complain is